# Deleting a Css rule from <head> using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css rule in styles.css in angular `#mat-dialog-0`, I want to delete this rule using javascript. this rule is added somehow dynamically. i want to delete this rule from the head while I am on a specific component. for that i need to use core javascript. But i am not sure how to select css rules in head using javascript.

Please help me

Comment: If you are trying to get rid of a certain style, you're probably better off overriding the style instead of removing the whole stylesheet.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot disable a specific CSS rule in a stylesheet. There is simply no approach designed to do it. It makes much more sense to perform DOM manipulation to achieve such an effect. And what we have in head are not CSS rules but stylesheets.

If you are looking to disable a stylesheet at specific index, that is entirely possible. For example:

```js
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];  // Selects the first stylesheet defined in <head>

stylesheet.disabled = true;  // The styling updates will be immediately applied
```